# Smartforms trigger new page for given condition

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

I have prepared a smart form, which has a table in main window. So there can be hundreds of lines in the table. What I want to do is to trigger new page for every 10 records.

I'have resized the main window to height that at most 10 records are fit and selected the new page  tick in command. It is kind of working but I want to do this programatically.

Like;

```
if count % 10 = 0
then GO_TO_NEW_PAGE
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to trigger a [Dynamic Page Break](http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/en/70/e17a37dec511d3b575006094192fe3/frameset.htm) using a [Command Node](http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/en/07/57f78ff5d111d4b65c006094192fe3/frameset.htm). I haven't tried what this does to the table header / footer though...